# TypeORM How to access reference relation field without loading relation entity

Tags: sql, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

As we know, to create ManyToOne/OneToMany relation we have to use @ManyToOne/@OneToMany decorators on a field.

In my project I have two entities: `Project` and `Position`.

This is how I created a relation:

```js
@Entity('positions')
export class Position {

  @ManyToOne(() => Project, {
    nullable: false,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  project: Project;

}
```

[TypeORM documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) says this code will create `projectId FOREIGN KEY` column in the database and store a project id in it.

Then when we trying to access `project` property TypeORM loads a project by the id stored in `projectId` field.

**QUESTION**

How can I access that `pojectId` field without loading a relational entity?

The property `projectId` does not exists by default in `Position` entity and if I manually create it it is not populated by `projectId` column value.

I have tried  this way:

```js
  @ManyToOne(() => Project, {
    nullable: false,
    eager: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  project: Project;

  projectId: string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@RelationId` decorator exported by `typeorm`. Using your example:

```js
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  RelationId,
  JoinColumn,
} from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class Position {
  @ManyToOne(() => Project, {
    nullable: false,
    eager: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  project: Project;

  @Column()
  @RelationId((position: Position) => position.project)
  projectId: string;
}
```